# Unable to get Proguard obfuscator and Sprint Boot to work together

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, proguard

**Summary**

I have been trying to get `Proguard` to work with `Spring-boot` for `obfuscation` but have not been able to get `Spring-boot` to run after building with `maven`.  I have searched and found some people talking about the same issue but I have not seen it resolved.

I have 2 applications.

- A2 requires A1
- A1

I only really need to build the `obfuscation` into A2 but ideally I would like to build it into both.

I am creating a `executable` `Spring-boot` jar to run A1 and A3.

I can get `maven` to package and create the `executable` `jar` but when I run it I get the stack trace below saying `compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression`.

**Question**

How can I get `proguard` to build my App without compressing the nested jars?

Thank you

**Stack Trace**

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open    nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism  used to create your executable jar file
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.c.k.e(JarFile.java:285)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.c.k.c(JarFile.java:260)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.c.k.a(JarFile.java:248)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.c.k.a(JarFile.java:237)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.a.c.a(JarFileArchive.java:103)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.a.c.a(JarFileArchive.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.a.c(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:72)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.c.a(Launcher.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
```

**Plugin details for POM**

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
   <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.13</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>proguard</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>proguard</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
      <!-- File with proguard configuration -->
      <proguardInclude>${basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
      <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
      <libs>
         <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
         <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
      </libs>
      <options>
         <option>-optimizations !class/marking/final</option>
         <option>-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/spring.*</option>
         <option>-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod</option>
         <option>-keepclasseswithmembers public class * { public static void main(java.lang.String[]);}</option>
      </options>
   </configuration>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
         <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
         <version>5.2.1</version>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**Proguard.conf**

```
# Don't obfuscate or remove your entry point
-keep public class com.something.InitialRunner{public static void main(java.lang.String[]);}

-ignorewarnings
-dontoptimize
-dontshrink


# Uncomment if you want to have more meaningful backtraces
# Useful for obfuscation debugging
# You absolutely must keep this commented out for production
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Comment: In Maven, are you putting all dependencies into a single jar for executing? This could be the problem. I've always had to keep Spring libraries outside of the executable jar for them to work correctly.

Comment: @JRSofty       Yes I was trying to have it build everything including Spring and all my libraries.  How do you setup your build then to exclude those libraries and use them at runtime?  Are you building the obfuscated jar without springs libraries then rebuilding to make one executable with that jar and spring?  Thank you

Comment: It could be that maven is performing the compression.  You might want to check the documentation. One check is to compile without the proguard and see if the jar runs or throws the same exception.

Comment: @JRSofty        The application runs fine without Proguard.  This only happens when it is added.  How did you build your application without spring in proguard are you able to post or email aaronmagi@gmail.com a sample pom with proguard setup.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So as we discussed in the comments above, here is how I handle this.

First step: Copy your dependencies to an external folder use the maven-dependency-plugin like this:

```
 <build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
         <executions>
           <execution>
             <id>copy-dependencies</id>
             <phase>package</phase>
             <goals>
               <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
               <outputDirectory> 
                 ${project.build.directory}/libs
               </outputDirectory>
               <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
               <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
               <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
               <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Step Two: Use Maven to perform your proguard. Now I'm not sure which proguard plugin you are using, I use the one from wvengen.

```
    <plugin>
       <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
       <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.12</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <phase>package</phase>
           <goals>
             <goal>proguard</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
             <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
             <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
             <proguardInclude>proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
             <libs>
               <lib>C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65/lib/rt.jar</lib>
               <lib>C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
             </libs>
           </configuration>
         </execution>
       </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Step Three: Check that your dependencies are listed in the proguard.conf file

```
# Use -libraryjars to list every jar found in the target/libs folder.

# Don't obfuscate or remove your entry point
-keep public class com.something.InitialRunner{public static void main(java.lang.String[]);}

-ignorewarnings
-dontoptimize
-dontshrink


# Uncomment if you want to have more meaningful backtraces
# Useful for obfuscation debugging
# You absolutely must keep this commented out for production
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Given there may be a way to automate this with Maven so that you don't have to add them all manually, this is however how I handle it. Once I keep Spring from being wrapped in the main jar before obfuscation then the application runs just fine.